# Auf meinem oder deinem Einhorn?

Tags: idiom

> Wollen wir heute mal zu einem veganen Restaurant?
>
> Auf meinem oder deinem Einhorn?

Was bedeutet *Auf meinem oder deinem Einhorn*?

Ich habe diese Redewendung bei Dict.cc nachgeschaut und es bedeutet *unicorn*.

Wisst ihr, was diese Redewendung ist?

Comment: I somehow do not believe that any dictionary returned *unicorn* for the whole phrase *(Auf meinem oder deinem Einhorn?).*

Comment: What exactly is to be misunderstood?

Comment: Auf Englisch: "Shall we ride on my unicorn or on your unicorn" - it means absolutely the same in English as in German. Someone is unwilling to eat vegan food unless you can supply a unicorn to ride to the restaurant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ich glaube nicht, dass das eine feste Redewendung ist. Der Satz ist elliptisch für

> Reiten wir auf meinem oder auf deinem Einhorn dahin?

Es gibt keine Einhörner; diese Art der Antwort suggeriert, dass die antwortende Person keine Lust hat, vegan essen zu gehen. (Etwa vergleichbar mit "Wenn Schweine fliegen." oder "Wenn die Hölle zufriert.")

Comment: Etwas Neues gelernt! Danke!

Comment: +1 Klingt plausibel. Aber ich habe diese Redewendung noch nie gehört. Hast Du vielleicht noch irgendeine Referenz dafür, oder Angaben, seit wann oder in welchem Umfeld sie gebraucht wird?

Comment: @Matthias: Wie gesagt, es ist meines Wissens keine feste Redewendung, sodass ich auch keine Referenz angeben kann. Es ist einfach eine "schlagfertige" Antwort, wie es sie auf lustigen Seiten im Netz öfter zu lesen gibt, und deren Bedeutung sich aus dem Kontext ergibt.

Comment: Teenager Jargon, der in einem Monat schon wieder vergessen sein kann. Individuelle Sprücheklopperei, die überhaupt nur in einer speziellen Clique verstanden werden. Außerhalb der Clique versteht das wohl kaum jemand.